# Cannot invoke method because [Object name].[instancevariable] is null

Tags: java, data-structures

I would appreciate if you help me sort a problem I cannot see how to fix since several hours. Here is a class that represents a data structure similar to a trie where I can make insertions of DNA sequences. The program reads an input file of commands such as:

insert AAACCCCGGTGAAAACGTA

insert ACTGGGAA

remove ACGT

insert ACCTT

insert ACTTA

print

For some reason when I try to run the method that executes the print command, it does not work telling me the print() method cannot be invoked because DNATreeNode.root is null. Here is the main file that runs the code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNAtree {

    private static DNATreeNode root;

    public DNAtree() {
        root = FlyweightNode.getFlyweight();
    }

    
    /**
     * Inserts a new sequence in this DNATree.
     * 
     * @param newSequence
     * @param idx             
     */
    public static void insert(String newSequence) {
        
        if (newSequence == null) {
            return;
        }
        
        // check sequence has valid characters
        if (!validSequence(newSequence.toCharArray())) {
            return;
        }
        
        LeafNode newNode = new LeafNode();
        newNode.insert(newSequence.toCharArray());
        
        
        // if root node is a FlyweightNode, we insert sequence directly.
        // root must become a LeafNode
        if (root instanceof FlyweightNode) {
            root = newNode; // root becomes a LeafNode
            System.out.print("Sequence " + newSequence + " inserted at level 0");
            
        } else if (root instanceof LeafNode) {
            // if root node is a LeafNode already, we need to split.
            LeafNode rootToLeaf = (LeafNode) root;
            
            // if sequence already exists, terminate function
            if (rootToLeaf.containsSequence(newNode)) {
                System.out.print("Sequence " + newSequence + " already exists");
                return;
            }
            
            //root = new InternalNode(); // split
            
            InternalNode newInternalRoot = (InternalNode) root;
            newInternalRoot.insert(rootToLeaf); // move leaf down
            newInternalRoot.insert(newNode); // insert new node
            
        } else if (root instanceof InternalNode) {
            InternalNode internalNode = (InternalNode) root;
            internalNode.insert(newNode);
        }
        
    }
    
    public void remove(String sequenceToRemove) {
        
    }
    
    public static void print() {
        root.print(0);
    }
    
    public static void printLengths() {
        //root.printLengths();
    }
    
    public static void printStats() {
        //root.printStats();
    }
    
    private static boolean validSequence(char[] sequence) {
        
        if (sequence == null) {
            return false;
        }
        
        if (sequence.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        
        String DNASequence = "ACGT";
        
        for (Character currChar : sequence) {
            if (!DNASequence.contains(currChar.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    public static void executeTreeOperation(String currentLine) {
        
        if (currentLine.trim().length() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        
        // separate every element and store them in array
        // this array should always contain only two elements
        String[] currentLineArr = currentLine.trim().split(" +");
        
        if (currentLineArr[0].equals("insert")) {
            insert(currentLineArr[1]);
            
        } else if (currentLineArr[0].equals("remove")) {
            System.out.println("we remove " + currentLineArr[1]);
            
        } else if (currentLineArr[0].equals("search")) {
            System.out.println("we search " + currentLineArr[1]);
            
        } else if (currentLineArr[0].equals("print")) {
            if (currentLineArr.length == 1) {
                print();
            } else if (currentLineArr[1].equals("lengths")) {
                printLengths();
            } else if (currentLineArr[1].equals("stats")) {
                printStats();
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param args the input file of commands
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0])); // Create new scanner
            DNAtree tree = new DNAtree();
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) { // While the scanner has information to
                                        // read
                tree.executeTreeOperation(sc.nextLine());
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I do not know what exactly I'm missing here, perhaps having some methods or variables as static are giving this issue? I'm aware there is already too much code being shown here but I thought it would give you a better idea seeing the complete class. Also you can see the additional classes at my repo: https://github.com/Jplaudir8/Data-Structures-and-Algorithms/tree/main/Project_2/src

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is in the [FlyweightNode](https://github.com/Jplaudir8/Data-Structures-and-Algorithms/blob/main/Project_2/src/FlyweightNode.java). It has a static method `getFlyweight` which returns a static data `flyweight`. But it is initialized in the constructor, which means that it won't be initialized unless you create an object of the `FlyweightNode` class.

Either remove all the static stuffs and use an instance of `FlyweightNode` or initialize the static field `flyweight` (not in the constructor).

P.S: Though my answer will fix the problem in your code, I'm not commenting/suggesting on the right way to use a Flyweight as my knowledge of the Flyweight design pattern is a bit rusty.